# What is use case of inFileViewerRootedAtPath in selectFile in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos

I have really hard time to understand the deference between this 2 codes! For me both working identical, not sure what apple try to explain [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524399-selectfile), looking to learn about the deference in use case.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.selectFile("/Users/test.txt", inFileViewerRootedAtPath: "/Users/test.txt")
```

and:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.selectFile("/Users/test.txt", inFileViewerRootedAtPath: "")
```

Comment: Which file viewers have you tried?

Comment: I did not understand your question, can you explain?

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=432280

Comment: Apparently Finder doesn't support a root path. I don't know if this is a bug.